# Running flask and python-telegram-bot (asyncio) in the same process

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, telegram

I am trying to initialize Flask and python-telegram-bot in the same process in Python 3.11. But the problem is that flask `app.run()` is blocking and python-telegram-bot uses asyncio.

Now, this is the code I have.

First in the main function I try to initialize my two modules

```
#main.py

from web_server import init_web_server
from telegram_bot import init_telegram_bot
import asyncio

async def main():
    init_web_server()
    await init_telegram_bot())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

For each module, I do what it has to. For Flask, I create a thread, and for python-telegram-bot I initialize the async application.

```
#web_server.py

import flask
import threading

def init_web_server():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True, use_reloader=False)).start()
```

```
#telegram_bot.py

import asyncio
from telegram.ext import Application

async def post_init(application: Application) -> None:
    print("Bot initialized")

async def init_telegram_bot():
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(token).post_init(post_init).build()
    await application.initialize()
    await application.start()
    await application.updater.start_polling()
```

But there's a problem here, since post_init never gets run (I never see the "Bot initialized" text on stdout). And I get an error: `Fetching updates got a asyncio.CancelledError. Ignoring as this task may onlybe closed via` Application.stop`.`

Been trying for a while to use `application.run_polling()` instead of `initialize() + start() + updater.start_polling()` but I think it internally does an asyncio.run() since I always get the `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running` error.

Any help to understand why this is not working would be appreciated. And if the solution allowed to have other libraries using asyncio (perhaps by the means of `gather()` function) it would be great.